# Can we write UI in activity xml as well UI in fragment xm?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I have create an activity and have 2 buttons. On click of each button fragment opens.
But when I do that fragment UI gets overlapped with activity UI.
I want to know if we can have UI components in both activity and fragment.
Also if have to keep the activity UI blank and create a new fragment from the activity for the UI.
Please let me kow how I can solve this.
Example of the code :

MainActivity.kt

```
 override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ")
        when(view!!.id){
            R.id.song_list->
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Songs list will be shown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                openFragment("Songs")
            }
            R.id.artist_list->
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Artist list will be shown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                openFragment("Artist")
            }
        }
    }

    fun openFragment(fragmentName: String){
        Log.d(TAG, "openFragment: ")
        if(fragmentName.equals("Songs")) {
            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, SongsFragment())
            transaction.disallowAddToBackStack()
            transaction.commit()
        }else{
            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, ArtistFragment())
            transaction.commit()
        }
    }
```

MainActivity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/song_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Songs List"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/artist_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Artist List"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/song_list"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

SongsFragment.kt

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container, false)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: ")
    }
```

SongsFragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SongsFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Please find the list of songs here" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see  you are missing some constrains on the Frame Layout that holds your fragments, if you set it as you like you can have your buttons and the fragment of your choice at the same time.